# responsive videoplayer with Header and Footer bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my video playing site look something like this. (There shouldnt be padding at the sides and top/bottom) [image] Where it fills out the screens width fully and height fully to the header and footer.

I keep getting some strange padding at the sides and bottom. The height is pushing down the footer. [image]

My current css/html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="header col-xs-12">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row video-container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <video autoplay loop="true">
        <source src="assets/videos/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer col-xs-12">
        <h2>Test</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Css

```
.container{
    width:100%;
}
video{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.header, .footer{
    background-color: #3FBCA3;
}

.padding-0{
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

I'm coding in Angular 2, and using bootstrap responsive grid system